# Accessing Secured Storage account from Synapse Notebook

Tags: azure-synapse-analytics

We have a Firewalled storage account which has a few files that we need to access via Synapse notebook. We do that with below code :

```
abfss_path = f'abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/data.csv'        
df = spark.read.load(abfss_path, format='csv',header=True)
display(df.limit(10))
```

The managed identity and my user (objectid) for the Synapse workspace has ' Storage Blob Data Contributor' role on the storage account.

The below have been enabled:

- Allow Azure services on the trusted services list to access this storage account.
- Specify resource instances that will have access to your storage account based on their system-assigned managed identity.

Running the above code works from the pipeline with a synapse notebook task but **fails when run from the studio through the notebook cell**.

Error : ***Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403***

I have tried everything but can't get it to work.

Via Pipeline

[image]

Via Studio Notebook Cell

[image]

I can see AAD (pass through) takes precedence when running from studio, so I tried running the session as 'managed Identity'. This doesn't change anything and I keep getting same error.

How to get this working?

Note : I am not using the managed vnet in my synapse workspace.

Comment: Can you chek please if you have the storage acount linked inside synapse workspace?
(magane->linked services)

Comment: @MBuschi : Yes it is and I can query it via the serverless sql pool with openrowset. The problem is while trying to read the file from sparkpool in a user session. It works from a pipeline via Managed identity.

Comment: Can you check if your AAD user and the managed identity have the same role in the storage account IAM role assignament blase?